# PHP How I can selected and drop a custom attr html with preg_match

Tags: php, html, replace, preg-replace

I have a html string like

```
<p lang="es-CO" style="text-align: center;" align="LEFT">
  <span style="font-family: 'comic sans ms', sans-serif;"> 
    <img class="alignnone" src="url" width="525" height="360" />
  </span>
</p>
```

And I want to remove all attr about all tags minus img's tag, for example. I mean, I want to select which attr I want to drop.

I want a result like this:

```
<p>
  <span> 
    <img src="url" width="525" height="360" />
  </span>
</p>
```

I know that `preg_replace("/<([a-z][a-z0-9]*)[^>]*?(\/?)>/i", '<$1$2>', $html);` delete all attr, but I did't want to remove the width and heght, for example...

It's possible select which attr or which tags I want to save or drop using `preg_replace`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rigth way to go is to use a html parser, but if your string is as simple as you've given, you could do:

```
$str = '<p lang="es-CO" style="text-align: center;" align="LEFT">
  <span style="font-family: \'comic sans ms\', sans-serif;"> 
    <img class="alignnone" src="url" width="525" height="360" />
  </span>
</p>';
$str = preg_replace('~<(?!\bimg\b)([a-z][a-z0-9]*)[^>]*(/?)>~is', '<$1$2>', $str);
echo $str,"\n";
```

**output:**

```
<p>
  <span> 
    <img class="alignnone" src="url" width="525" height="360" />
  </span>
</p>
```

`(?!\bimg\b)` is a [negative look ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that checks there're no `img` tag to be replaced.

Comment: Thanks, but, how I could select which attr I want to remove? Something like "I want to remove the attr in [lang|style|align|class|other]", for example.

Comment: @Chemaclass: it will be too complex for a single regex. You have to use a parser. For example DOMDocument : http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php